# Express a product of disjoint cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

I'm working on this permutation and write that in terms of disjoint cycles: $(7236)(85)(571)(1537)(486)$. Since $(1537)$ and $(486)$ are disjoint, I computed the 3 middle cycles from right to left and obtained $(17853)$. i.e. $(7236)(17853)(486)$. Now does that matter which two cycles I should compute first? Does $\tau\circ \sigma\circ \delta= \tau(\sigma(\delta)?$ Thanks!

Comment: You mean I think $(f\circ g)\circ h = f\circ (g\circ h)$, that is both send $x$ to the same place.

Comment: @Matthew Towers Thanks, just updated the notation

Comment: @ancient mathematician Thanks, I think they should refer to different permutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the order in which you perform the computations does not matter. This is because composition (the operation from which “cycle product” stems) is **associative** - this means $f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h$.

In your case, you can put the parenthesis around the middle terms in order to perform those products first.